# echo specific value from mysql array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So i am trying to echo values from the mysql table using php (wordpress)

most of the fieds are showing fine

but when i try to echo

$row->form i get an array returned like this:

```
string(832) "[{"id":"1","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"First name","value":"firstname1"},{"id":"2","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Last name","value":"lastname1"},{"id":"6","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Accomodation","value":"Hotel Sample"},{"id":"3","is_email":"true","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Email","value":"sample@example.com"},{"id":"4","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Phone","value":"333333"},{"id":"5","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Message","value":"Goog Job"}]" 

string(973) "[{"id":"1","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"First name","value":"ddd"},{"id":"2","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Last name","value":"ddd"},{"id":"3","is_email":"true","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Email","value":"sample1@example.com"},{"id":"6","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Accomodation\/PikUp Address:","value":"House no 203"},{"id":"8","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Room Number:","value":"d"},{"id":"4","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Phone","value":"44444"},{"id":"5","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Message","value":"444444"}]"
```

**Here's my sql code:**

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_table_1");

foreach($result as $row)
 {
echo $row->form;
}
```

i wish to echo the first name. Thanks

Comment: you missed closing quotes on your query  "SELECT * FROM wp_table_1 should be "SELECT * FROM wp_table_1" ...missed last quote

Comment: thanks for the point out but that was me missed while writing here.

Comment: Try `$row->form[0]->value` in this case. Since you are presenting JSON-Strings instead of an array, you might need `json_decode` before.

Comment: Thanks Quasimodo it did help me upto certain extent. Now i am facing a little issue that i am trying to access first name for each array and in each case the index value of first name array is different. What do you suggest

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $row->form;
```

The above line will echo array.

To echo only first name use as in following pattern

```
echo $row->form['first_name'];
```

Comment: hi thanks for the suggestion but the there is no such column as first name you can see the value being stored like this "value":"firstname1"

Comment: also as you can see for each field there are multiple arrays and first array contains the first name as value

Answer (score 0):

This is only a workaround if you can not find a proper solution. You should try something like `get_var()` or `get_col()` instead. Consult the [wordpress reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

```
<?php             
$rows = [ 
'
[ {"id":"1","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"First name","value":"firstname1"},
  {"id":"2","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Last name","value":"lastname1"},
  {"id":"6","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Accomodation","value":"Hotel Sample"},
  {"id":"3","is_email":"true","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Email","value":"sample@example.com"},
  {"id":"4","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Phone","value":"333333"},
  {"id":"5","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Message","value":"Goog Job"}
] 
',

'
[ {"id":"1","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"First name","value":"ddd"},
  {"id":"2","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Last name","value":"ddd"},
  {"id":"3","is_email":"true","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Email","value":"sample1@example.com"},
  {"id":"6","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Accomodation\/PikUp Address:","value":"House no 203"},
  {"id":"8","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Room Number:","value":"d"},
  {"id":"4","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Phone","value":"44444"},
  {"id":"5","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Message","value":"444444"}
] 
'];

var_dump($rows);

$names = [ 1 => 'firstname', 2 => 'lastname' ];
foreach($rows as &$row)
{
  $row = json_decode($row);
  $cols = [];
  foreach($row as &$col)
  { 
    if(isset($names[$col->id]))
      $cols[$names[$col->id]] = $col;
  }
  $row = $cols;
}

var_dump($rows);
```

Result is:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'firstname' => 
        object(stdClass)[1]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'is_email' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'add_to_day_hour_info' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'add_to_day_hour_body' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'translation' => string 'First name' (length=10)
          public 'value' => string 'firstname1' (length=10)
      'lastname' => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          public 'is_email' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'add_to_day_hour_info' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'add_to_day_hour_body' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'translation' => string 'Last name' (length=9)
          public 'value' => string 'lastname1' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'firstname' => 
        object(stdClass)[5]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'is_email' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'add_to_day_hour_info' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'add_to_day_hour_body' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'translation' => string 'First name' (length=10)
          public 'value' => string 'ddd' (length=3)
      'lastname' => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          public 'is_email' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'add_to_day_hour_info' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'add_to_day_hour_body' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'translation' => string 'Last name' (length=9)
          public 'value' => string 'ddd' (length=3)
```